# Relation between reverse saturation current and temperature in diode

Tags: diodes

Suppose diode has reverse saturation current of Is at 20 degree Celsius. How to calculate its reverse saturation current at 65 degrees Celsius?

Note: I know reverse saturation current doubles for every 10 degree rise in temperature.

Comment: Why not use a simulator and the diode's model. It will be far more accurate than a hand calculation.

Comment: If it doubles for 10 C, then it 'root2s' for 5 C. 45 C difference is 4 doublings => 16, then a further 1.414 for the last 5. You do the rest of the arithmetic.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you actually want the *Is* value, saturation current temperature dependency in the standard SPICE diode model is defined by three additional parameters:

TNOM  nominal parameter measurement temperature (default 27°C)

EG bandgap energy (default 1.11 eV for silicon)

XTI saturation current temperature exponent (default 3.0 for p-n junction diode)

So Is(T2) is  (from Semiconductor Device Modeling with Spice -- Paolo Antognetti, Giuseppe Massobrio):

$$
I_S(T_2) = I_S(T_1) {\left( \frac{T_2}{T_1} \right)}^{\rm{XTI}/n} \exp
\left[ - \frac{q\,E_g(300)} {n\,k\,T_2} \left( 1-\frac{T_1}{T_2} \right) \right],
\tag{1-48}
$$

where \$T_1 = T_{NOM}\$ in Kelvin, and \$n\$ is the ideality factor.

Using a SPICE simulation directly may not yield the correct answer. At best it has a resistance Roff  (default 1/GMIN) in parallel. There are several distinct regions used in SPICE simulation. If Roff is set very high and you have a negative bias that is more negative than -5*Vt you should get close.

Comment: For reference, the first important paper I'm aware of on this is  P. E. Gray, D. DeWitt, A. R. Boothroyd and J. F. Gibbons, "Physical Electronics and Circuit Models of Transistors," *SEEC*, Vol. 2, p. 48, J. Wiley, 1964, which was also important because they discuss the temperature dependence of diffusivity that was neglected in the equation when the power was fixed at 3. (This is approximated with XTI in the current model.) But it is still "curve-fitting" and doesn't exactly match behaviors, memory serving. +1

Comment: I wish there was a way to upvote @Kuba for that splendid equation editing above!